# What options are there to use variable length capture groups with negative look-behinds in .Net?

Tags: .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm parsing text that a user will enter into an application.  I Need the ability to look at positive and negative assertions by the user.

For example if my regex is

```
"(did|will)(?&lt;!\bnot\W+)\s+show\s+dog"
```

These examples don't match as expected:

```
did not show dog
did not show
not show dog
```

This matches as expected:

```
did show dog
```

This one doesn't match but should:

```
show dog
```

I would like to be able to make the first capture group optional, saying using the ? qualifier for (did|use)? however, when doing so, it becomes variable length and breaks.

What options there to parse the example text above with the first capture group being optional?

I'm using the .Net regular expression engine.  I only have the ability to pass in a regular expression to determine a match.  I can't access any other .Net parameters beyond what is in the regex text.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group `\s+` together with `(did|will)`, else, when you make the capturing group optional, the `\s+` requires a whitespace before the `show dog`, that is why it does not match.

Use

```
\b(?:(did|will)\s+)?(?<!\bnot\W+)show\s+dog\b
```

See the [regex demo at the online .NET regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3A%28did%7Cwill%29%5Cs%2B%29%3F%28%3F%3C!%5Cbnot%5CW%2B%29show%5Cs%2Bdog%5Cb&i=did%20not%20show%20dog%20did%20not%20show%20not%20show%20dog%0D%0Adid%20show%20dog%0D%0Ashow%20dog).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:(did|will)\s+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `(did|will)` - Group 1: `did` or `will`
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<!\bnot\W+)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, there is a whole word `not` followed with 1+ non-word chars
- `show\s+dog` - `show`, 1+ whitespaces, `dog`
- `\b` - word boundary